# How to set an impulse different from 1 in Python (IRF in VAR model)

Tags: python, statistics, var

Good morning everyone,
I built a Vector autoregressive model (Var) on Python and I’m traying the apply an Impulse response function (IRF) to my model.

I would like to set the function giving to the impulse a value of 0.5 (not the common 1). In detail I want plot a graph were the ‘Shadow_rate’ is my impulse variable and I want to observe the effect on my ‘GDP’ variable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql2at.png)

Can you say me how to set the magnitude of the impulse within my function?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide the script you have tried so far

Comment: var_01 = VAR(df_01)                                                                                          
vresults_01 = var_01.fit(4)                                                                
vresults_01.summary()                                                                                                  irf_01 = vresults_01.irf(24)                                                                                        temppl1 = irf_01.plot(impulse='Shadow_Rate', response='GDP')